# Pluralize [pull-up] and [chin-up] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[pull-up](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pull-up) is one of the few tags that is singular without a good reason.

Contrary we have most others in plural.

- Comparable tags like [sit-ups](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sit-ups) and [push-ups](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/push-ups) are plural.
- Unrelated tags like [abdominals](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abdominals) [legs](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legs) are plural, too.
- Only tags where plural doesn't make sense, like [pain](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pain) or [bellyfat](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bellyfat) are singular.

I know that pull-ups are a hard exercise and most people are completely happy if the can do one, but I think we should encourage people to do [pull-ups](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pull-ups) and not just one [pull-up](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pull-up).

Edit: I've just discovered that the [chin-up](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chin-up) tag is subject to the same issue. Most likely because it is nearly as hard.

Comment: Note: Although some of the wording might not be, my request is serious after all.

Comment: Most likely because people on this site tend to be asking how to get past the first one. :) Good catch, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a reason to keep those tags singular either. I would rather one or the over, but in the context of what those exercises are, I would keep the plural forms.

I've merged [pull-up](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pull-up) into [pull-ups](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pull-ups) and [chin-up](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chin-up) into [chin-ups](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chin-ups).

Thanks for catching this!

Comment: Great,    thank you!